# How to find Google Apps Script sending Mail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

A year ago, I set up a Google Sheet + Script combo to send a daily summary email to a team. I need to make changes to it but can't find it (I've spent a lot of time trying to find it).

Unfortunately, the actual sheet isn't updated, so it doesn't show up in recently modified documents.

It's sent at a specific time each day. Does anyone have any tips/tricks that might help me find it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open any Spreadsheet → Tools → Script Editor.
2. In Script Editor go to Edit → All your triggers

There you'll filnd the name of script function of your trigger: you may find it leter with `getHandlerFunction()`, see Edit.

## Edit

You may write a script to loop all your files in drive and get all their installsble triggers.

Use this sample code to get files trigers:

**getUserTriggers(document)**

> Gets all installable triggers owned by this user in the given
>   document, for this script or add-on only. This method cannot be used
>   to see the triggers attached to other scripts.
>
> ```
>  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
>  var triggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(ss);
>  // Log the event type for the first trigger in the array.
>  Logger.log(triggers[0].getHandlerFunction());
> ```

Use this code to get all spreadsheets in drive:

```
  var arr = [];
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    file = files.next();
    arr.push([file.getName(), file.getUrl(), file.getId()])
  }
 Logger.log(arr);
```

Code from this Q: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/n7b4e6H5Fss/3dkkRVs_BAAJ